# JSON object lookup using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JSON object and code

```
    <script>
    function lookuptable(val)
    {
     var result="";
     var lookup= [
     {"title":"some title","ID":"abc:name/path/"},
     {"title":"some title1","ID":"abc:name/path1/"},
     {"title":"some title","ID":"abc:name/path/","anothertitle":"anothertitle"}
     ];
     result = lookup[val];
     return result;
    }
    lookuptable("abc:name/path/")
   </script>
```

I am passing id and expecting to get title, id and it has any other fields. it is not working as expected. any suggestions?

Comment: lookup is an array, so `lookup['id']` will be undefined - you'll need to use array filter method - `return lookup.filter(({ID}) => ID === val)`

Comment: yes I am getting undefined.. any suggestions how pass ID and get entire row?

Answer (score 0):

Here, `lookup` is `array` not `object` so `lookup[id]` is not defined.
To find the correct item by id, you can use `Array.find` method.

```js
var lookup= [
  {"title":"some title","ID":"abc:name/path/"},
  {"title":"some title1","ID":"abc:name/path1/"},
  {"title":"some title","ID":"abc:name/path/","anothertitle":"anothertitle"}
];

function lookuptable(val) {
  var result = lookup.find((item) => item['ID'] === val);
  return result;
}

console.log(lookuptable("abc:name/path/"));
```